# How to minimize Excel while my application is running?

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I minimize Excel and new opened excel while my application is running?

I have written the following code, but the code fails.

If you wonder why I want to minimize Excel that is because my application fails if user clicks any excel cell!

```
Imports System.Management
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 100
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

setting `Visible` to `False` is wrong, it's not minimized.
Need to set `Visible` to `true` AND minimized

```
        oXL.Visible = True
        oXL.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
```

Answer (score 1):

I done a similar thing to my Word application to hide it when I'm using `Word` object for spell checking. I'm very positive you can do that to excel also;

```
Excel._Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = false;
excel.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false;
```

NOTE: The code is in C#.Net